# MVC Preview 4 - No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route that I am calling through a RedirectToRoute like this:

```
return this.RedirectToRoute("Super-SuperRoute", new { year = selectedYear });
```

I have also tried:

```
 return this.RedirectToRoute("Super-SuperRoute", new { controller = "Super", action = "SuperRoute", id = "RouteTopic", year = selectedYear });
```

The route in the global.asax is like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Super-SuperRoute", // Route name
    "Super.mvc/SuperRoute/{year}",  // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Super", action = "SuperRoute", id = "RouteTopic" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

So why do I get the error: "No route in the route table matches the supplied values."?

I saw that the type of selectedYear was var.  When I tried to convert to int with int.Parse I realised that selectedYear was actually null, which would explain the problems.  I guess next time I'll pay more attention to the values of the variables at a breakpoint :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What type is selectedYear? A DateTime? If so then you might need to convert to a string.