# return RedirectToAction(...) prettier url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, redirecttoaction

Is there any possible way to maintain the format of my link as defined in the `RouteConfig.cs` mappings when calling `RedirectToAction` method?

**ex [just for test]:**

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Token Verification",
 "Registration/TokenVerification/{ConfernceId}/{TokenType}/{TokenId}/{Email}",
new{
  controller="Registration",
  action="TokenVerification",
  ConfernceId= 0,
  TokenType='\0',
  TokenId="",
  Email=""
 }
);
```

I can call this link and my action if being routed correctly:

> http://localhost:49619/Registration/TokenVerification/2/R/asdasdasd/someone@somewhere.com

But if I called `RedirectToAction`, it will generate the following `url`

> http://localhost:49619/Registration/TokenVerification?ConfernceId=2&TokenType=R&Email=someone%40somewhere.com

It is working also, but it is not pretty at all!

Any suggestions ?

Comment: TokenId and Email look optional because you are setting them to string.Empty. These are path values, so they must have a value for the routing to work.

Comment: @EmmaMiddlebrook, thank you, this was the problem I faced with routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectToRoute` (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992853(v=vs.110).aspx)) to generate urls which are in format of specified routes.

```
 return RedirectToRoute("Token Verification", new
        {
            ConfernceId = 0,
            TokenType = "0",
            TokenId = "0",
            Email = "0"
        });
```

If you want to generate links, then check below perocess.
use `Url.RouteUrl` (check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx) resource). Say For example -

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute=true, controller="Albums", id=3})
```

will generate `/api/Albums/3`

In your case, it should be -

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Token Verification", new
{
    controller = "Registration",
    action = "TokenVerification",
    ConfernceId = 0,
    TokenType = "0",
    TokenId = "0",
    Email = "0"
})
```

And it will generate - `/Registration/TokenVerification/0/0/0/0`

Comment: it seems logical solution, but i cant get it to work, i keep receiving `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.` I've searched for similar issues online, but still couldn't solve it.  I pass the same types and same order of parameters as in the defined route as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690/mvc-preview-4-no-route-in-the-route-table-matches-the-supplied-values)